Why is the block breaking sound playing twice for this custom item?
I have a custom item created with Minecraft Fabric (server-side) using the "Polymer" library (https://github.com/Patbox/Polymer). When breaking a block broken instantly with this item, the block breaking sound plays twice. The code for the item is below:
package com.eesa.watermelonsmp;

import eu.pb4.polymer.core.api.item.PolymerItem;
import net.minecraft.block.BlockState;
import net.minecraft.block.Blocks;
import net.minecraft.block.StemBlock;
import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;
import net.minecraft.entity.ExperienceOrbEntity;
import net.minecraft.entity.LivingEntity;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.PlayerEntity;
import net.minecraft.item.*;
import net.minecraft.server.network.ServerPlayerEntity;
import net.minecraft.server.world.ServerWorld;
import net.minecraft.text.Text;
import net.minecraft.util.ActionResult;
import net.minecraft.util.math.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.world.World;

public class WatermelonHoe extends HoeItem implements PolymerItem {
    public static final WatermelonMaterial WATERMELON_MATERIAL = new WatermelonMaterial();

    public WatermelonHoe(Settings settings) {
        super(WATERMELON_MATERIAL, -2, 0, settings);
    }

    @Override
    public Item getPolymerItem(ItemStack itemStack, ServerPlayerEntity player) {
        return Items.DIAMOND_HOE;
    }
}

And WatermelonMaterial:
package com.eesa.watermelonsmp;

import net.minecraft.item.Items;
import net.minecraft.item.ToolMaterial;
import net.minecraft.recipe.Ingredient;

public class WatermelonMaterial implements ToolMaterial {
    @Override
    public int getDurability() {
        return 3047;
    }

    @Override
    public float getMiningSpeedMultiplier() {
        return 10.0F;
    }

    @Override
    public float getAttackDamage() {
        return 5.0F;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMiningLevel() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getEnchantability() {
        return 22;
    }

    @Override
    public Ingredient getRepairIngredient() {
        return Ingredient.ofItems(Items.MELON); // MELON is MELON BLOCK.
    }

}

How can I fix this issue?
